# Efficient three valued compare

Tags: assembly, optimization, x86

For **unsigned** integers getting the result of

```
if (a>b) => 1
if (a=b) => 0
if (a<b) => -1
```

Can be optimized into the branchless version

```
return ((a > b) - (a < b))
```

This can be written into x86 assembly like so:

```
4829D1           cmp rcx,rdx
0F94C1           setz cl    
19C0             sbb eax,eax    
83D8FF           sbb eax,-$01    
D3E8             shr eax,cl

13 bytes in total
```

Is there a way to do this without branches in less than 5 instructions or in fewer bytes?

Comment: What's the rationale here?  Are you concerned about instruction-cache pressure?

Comment: Once you've profiled all the various suggestions, can you post some timing results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with less bytes (11 bytes) and one less instruction (4 instructions) which may be faster:

```
483bca          cmp     rcx,rdx
1bc0            sbb     eax,eax
483bd1          cmp     rdx,rcx
83d000          adc     eax,0
```

This can be improved upon to 10 bytes if you have a spare register known to be null.

```
...
11d8            adc     eax,ebx
```

Comment: Like this, because it does not change a byte register. A partial register write can cause a pipeline stall.

Comment: It's difficult to select a correct answer. Went with this one because of its simplicity and because it does not use byte registers. There is even room for further improvement, hence the award.

Answer (score 4):

Clang 3.7 produces the following x86-64 machine code for me:

```
0:   48 39 f7                cmp    rcx,rdx
3:   0f 97 c0                seta   al
6:   0f b6 c0                movzx  eax,al
9:   83 d8 00                sbb    eax,0x0
```

That's four instructions for the computation; the result is in `eax`.

This can be improved upon:

```
0:   31 C0                   xor eax,eax
2:   48 39 D1                cmp rcx,rdx
5:   0F 97 C0                setnbe al
8:   83 D8 00                sbb eax,0x0
```

11 bytes.